# Button from another form submitting 2 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 separate form that are working fine, but my subscribe button is calling add comment form. So when button from second form is clicked my `add_comment.js` is also called. On my website I have only buttons for subscribtion and for adding comments on one specific page. I'd like to make my `add_comment` called when form or button with specific `id` is clicked or submitted and every other button to call `news.js` which is working fine. I searched for answer but none was good for me

**First Form**

```
<form name ="add_comment" id="add_comment" class="comment-form">
//some inputs name, email..
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="buttonKomentar">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Second Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"> 
<button class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="buttonSub">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

**News.js**

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dodaj_za_news.php",
        data: { 
            email: $("#email").val(), 
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#news').html(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            $('#news').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

**add_comment.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#buttonKomentar").on("click", function(e){
              $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'add_comment.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              $('#potvrda').html(data);                }
          });
          });

        });
```

Comment: `$("button")` selects all `button` elements on the page. You're then adding a `click` event to all of those buttons. If you only want it to select buttons with an ID of `buttonSub`, use `$("#buttonSub")`, much like you did for `$("#buttonKomentar")`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes I did that intentionally. My goal is to have all buttons call `dodaj_za_news.php` , but only one button/form to call `add_comment.js` which is not working. However when I press button from second form with `id  = buttonSub` my `add_comment.js` is called

Comment: Well, it's not at all clear what you're seeing happening. Perhaps you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

First form doesn't have closing tag. If it is the same in your code, then the second form is treated as a part of parent form.